# In openMDAO, how important is it to eliminate inactive constraints?

Tags: openmdao

Will there be a meaningful increase in solution speed if inactive constraints are removed (say wing stiffness was dominating wing max stress, so stress constraint inactive)? Is it more of a problem for the optimisation drivers themselves, or does openMDAO have any tricks to help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenMDAO does not change the size of the optimization problem during execution (the number of design variables and constraints) and most optimizer's don't allow this.

Many optimizer's already employ an active set approach.  While the framework is required to compute partials of potentially inactive constraints, this often isn't a significant performance hit.

Obviously this depends on the size of the problem involved and the cost of computing constraints.  There are some tricks for aggregating large vector constraints into a single constraint (http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/components/ks_comp.html), but I wouldn't worry about this unless you're confident that your constraint evaluation is a performance bottleneck.